# How to correctly use wx.SingleChoice in Python

Tags: python, wxpython

Im quite new in python and I would like to show a SingleChoiceDialog box with a list of strings from an sqlite query but I do something wrong and the list in the box shows just the last of the value of the variable list.

The query:

```
            sql = u"select person.name from person"
            c.execute(sql)
            for row in c.execute(sql):
                    z = list(row)
```

The Dialog box:

```
        def whatusr(parent=None, message='', default_value=''):
                dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(
                        self, "Who?", 'The Caption',
                        z,
                        wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE
                        )
                if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                        print 'You selected: %s\n' % dlg.GetStringSelection()
                dlg.Destroy()
```

When I run this, the Dialog box shows just the last value of the list and not all the list.
I think this is because the Dialog box wants me to have an other form of list.
My list `z = list(row)` outputs the value as: `[a], [b], [c], ..` but the Dialog box is probably expecting the value in this form: `[a,b,c, ..]`. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to create your list from the returned sql statement using only the first element i.e. item[0].

```
import sqlite3
import wx
db = sqlite3.connect('/home/rolf/my.db',)
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute('person.name from person')
stats = cur.fetchall()
def xApp():
    z=[]
    for i in stats:
        z.append(i[0])
    dlg = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None,"Which","title",z,wx.CHOICEDLG_STYLE)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        print 'You selected: %s\n' % dlg.GetStringSelection()
    dlg.Destroy()
x=wx.App()
xApp()
x.MainLoop()
```

or you could use:

```
z = [item[0] for item in stats]
```

as mentioned by Mike Driscoll but you still need only the first element

Comment: Thx!
z=[] 
for i in stats:
        z.append(i[0])

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `wx.SingleChoiceDialog` widget does indeed require a normal list in the form of `[a,b,c, ..]` as you surmised. What you are probably getting is a list of lists and the widget doesn't know how to display that correctly.

I would just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract the items from the row. Something like this should work:

```
z = [item for item in row]
```

I hope this helps.